# Automatically resize div to width of page each time page expands

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want a my div #title to stretch horizontally across the entire top of my page. Using my CSS below this works fine. However, I allow the user to add elements to my page using jQuery and when this happens the page expands horizontally and the user can scroll left and right. Unfortunately, my #title div doesn't expand when the page expands and stays the width of the original page. Is there any way to make the div automatically expand to the width of the page each time the page width changes?

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        ...
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="title">
            <p class="title_banner_words" id="title_words">My Title</p>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html {
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    padding: 0; 
    margin: 0;
}    

body {
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    position: relative; 
    padding: 0; 
    margin: 0;
}

#title {
    background-color: #35373b;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: add `jsfiddle.net` samle with markup and jquery

Comment: @Morre, thanks, but getting rid of that doesn't help. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
    function methodToFixLayout() {
        winWidth = $(window).width();
        console.log(" " + winWidth);
        $('#title').css('width', winWidth / divide with a number which suits); //Ex: winWidth / 12.49
       $('p').css('float','left');
       }

    $(document).ready(function(){
      methodToFixLayout();
    });

    $(window).resize(function(){
            methodToFixLayout();
        });
</scipt>
```

I hope this will Help.

Comment: thanks! but I can't seem to get $(window).resize(function(){... to work. Even if I just set a simple alert inside of it. Doesn't seem to recognize that the page is being resized...

Comment: you must have jquery library included in your html.

Comment: @JoeDanger As Vicky said You must include jquery library before your script. I updated the Answer.